# SmartCard MUTUAL AUTHENTICATION

Tags: applet, smartcard, mutual-authentication

Hi I'm looking for information about working MUTUAL AUTHENTICATION with SmartCards, I wonder if you can help me.
I'm working on reverse engineering apdu commands and would like to know how to calculate MAC.
For example I have the following:

```
APPLET: A4 00 04 0C XX XX XX
APDU: 00 84 00 00 08 C9
TRX: 00 82 00 00 28 [seed bytes Transformed enc mac ...] 00
TRX: B0 0C 0D 81 00 97 01 5D 8E 08 [MAC] 00
```

The first two commands I understand them perfectly, but starting in the third one 00 82 is where I would like to know how to calculate the MAC and what follows, to make the readings
I would like to know information and documents to read and learn more about MUTUAL AUTHENTICATION

Comment: What kind of smart card do you use? Which version of global-platform it is compatible with?

Comment: I do not know, is research, but the card has a PKCS15 applet. as could be determined?

Comment: if it helps the applet using MUTUAL AUTHENTICATION is this: A4 00 04 0C 07 A0 00 00 02 47 10 01 53

Comment: What is the ATRof your card?

Comment: I've tried several, and all are as follows:
3B FD 96 FE 00 00 81 31 45 00 00 01 XX XX XX XX 00 00 00 00 00 00 XX
I have noticed that those 4 bytes change. To widen you a little more, the cards are issued by the thousands.

Comment: Get a specification of the application, anything else is a waste of time. You won't be able to reverse engineer much without knowledge of algorithm and key value to apply, even if you would know exactly the command structure. ISO 7816-4, the first place to search, states for the command data field of MUTUAL AUTHENTICATE just "authentication related data", and so does not help much here.

Comment: at least and me together a little more ... a general reading material to help me learn more about MUTUAL AUTHENTICATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short summary of Mutual Authenticate in general (I agree, ISO 7816-4 is a bit terse on the meaning concentrating on the interface):

- Mutual Authenticate is the combination of an Internal Authenticate and an External Authenticate command.
- First a host application requests a random number from the card.
- Then this random number is somehow encrypted using a secret key, typically by applying a MAC algorithm
- The computation result is sent back to the card in the command data field of Mutual Authenticate, with another random number generated outside.
- The card verifies the MAC result and if successful grants an access right. It also computes a MAC from the externally supplied random number using a different key, and sends this as command response. If unsuccessful some provision against brute force is made, either by an error counter blocking the key or by a substantial delay.
- The host application verifies the MAC from the card. If the result is correct, the host application can be sure, its a "legal" card.

Two points are critical:

- how to separate and encode MAC and externally provided random number - e.g. as TLV structure using two data objects
- how to identify **both** keys, since in P2 just one can be specified.